# Can I use mod on a String?

Tags: java

So I got this task to complete a method called "remove5List". This method has to remove every object with mod5==0 of a given LinkedList of type String.

My approach was that I use the mod operator, but it only works with Integer I guess. Now I got to a point where I don't know how to continue.

This is my first post here and I'm a total beginner, so correct me if I did something wrong.

//edit: The list is filled with **numbers**

```java
static void remove5List(List<String> list)
    {
        ListIterator<String> iter = list.listIterator();


        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            //here I would like to check if I can divide the obj by 5
        }
    }
```

Comment: If a `String` contains letters how do you define mod here?

Comment: use `Integer.parseInt(number) %5 == 0` to check divisible by 5 or not .

Comment: if the list is filled with numbers, why are they of type String ?

Comment: If your list is filled with numbers (which I'm not sure why), you can use `Integer.parseInt(iter.next())` and then compute mod

Comment: If the string doesn't represent an integer, then get the bytes from the string, sum them, and then mod the sum.

Comment: Thank you @KhalidShah!
I got this task from university, just for completion. I don't know why they used type String there..

Comment: This answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java.

Answer (score 1):

Please keep integers as integers

```
static void remove5List(List<String> list) {
            ListIterator<String> iter = list.listIterator();

            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                boolean mod = false;
                try {
                    int number = Integer.parseInt(iter.next());
                    if (number % 5 == 0) {
                        mod = true;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
    //if mod == true ,you can divide the obj by 5
            }
        }
```